# How tempDB works?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tempdb

I am trying to understand the `tempDB` and following are the doubts popping in my mind.

1. What is the lifetime of data in `tempDB`? Say a query is doing some `Order By` and uses `tempDB` for performing that. After this query finishes, someone else also executes a query which utilizes the `tempDB`. Will the second query find records written by first query in the `tempDB` or will they be deleted?
2. Are there any ***visible*** tables created inside the `tempDB` by the Sql Engine? How can I know which temporary table is created because of this query? Is there any naming convention followed by the Sql engine for naming these temporary tables?

I am new to `tempDB` so please pardon me for asking such silly (if at all) questions :-)

*It will be very nice if someone can point me to a good resource which can help me learn about tempDB.*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Temp table is stored in tempdb until the connection is dropped (or in the case of a global temp tables when the last connection using it is dropped). You can also (and it is a good practice to do so) manually drop the table when you are finished using it with a drop table statement.

No, others cannot see your temp tables if they are local temp tables (They can see and use global temp tables) Multiple people can run commands which use the same temp table name but they will not be overlapping in a local temp table and so you can have a table named #test and so can 10,000 other users, but each one has its own structure and data.

You don't want to generally look up temp tables in tempdb. It is possible to check for existence, but that is the only time I have ever referenced tempdb directly. Simply use your temp table name. Example below of checking for existence

```
  IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB.dbo.#DuplicateAssignments') IS NOT NULL 
  BEGIN 
  DROP TABLE #DuplicateAssignments 
  END
```

You name temp tables by prefacing the name with # (for local tables the ones you would use 999.9% of the time) and ## for global temp tables, then the rest of the name you want.

Comment: All temp tables are in 'tempDB' database (?) then what do you mean by global and local temp tables.. please explain

Comment: @peakit - Local temporary tables are specific to a given connection.  Global temporary tables are visible to all connections.

Comment: I saw that someone is doing: IF object_id(N'tempdb..#MyTempTable', N'U') IS NOT NULL 
 DROP TABLE #MyTempTable

Could you please explain what is this 'N' in the first and second argument of objectId method doing?

Comment: Thanks HLGEM.. this may also interest you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596203/local-vs-global-temp-tables-when-to-use-what

Answer (score 3):

There's a few MSDN articles that are probably the best source of information on the tempDB database in SQL Server.

[tempdb Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190768.aspx)

> The tempdb system database is a global
> resource that is available to all
> users connected to the instance of SQL
> Server and is used to hold the
> following:
>
> - Temporary user objects that are explicitly created, such as: global or
>   local temporary tables, temporary
>   stored procedures, table variables, or
>   cursors.
> - Internal objects that are created by the SQL Server Database Engine, for
>   example, work tables to store
>   intermediate results for spools or
>   sorting.
> - Row versions that are generated by data modification transactions in a
>   database that uses read-committed
>   using row versioning isolation or
>   snapshot isolation transactions.
> - Row versions that are generated by data modification transactions for
>   features, such as: online index
>   operations, Multiple Active Result
>   Sets (MARS), and AFTER triggers.
>
> Operations within tempdb are minimally
> logged. This enables transactions to
> be rolled back. tempdb is re-created
> every time SQL Server is started so
> that the system always starts with a
> clean copy of the database. Temporary
> tables and stored procedures are
> dropped automatically on disconnect,
> and no connections are active when the
> system is shut down. Therefore, there
> is never anything in tempdb to be
> saved from one session of SQL Server
> to another. Backup and restore
> operations are not allowed on tempdb.

There's also [tempdb and Index Creation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188281.aspx), [this blog post](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/Kimberly/post/Understanding-TempDB-table-variables-v-temp-tables-and-Improving-throughput-for-TempDB.aspx) along with [Working with tempdb in SQL Server 2005](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc966545.aspx) which states:

> The SQL Server system database, tempdb, has undergone a number of changes in SQL Server 2005. There are new tempdb usages and internal optimizations in SQL Server 2005; tempdb architecture is mostly unchanged since SQL Server 2000.
>
> **The tempdb system database is very similar to a user database. The main difference is that data in tempdb does not persist after SQL Server shuts down.**

Comment: If you're a non-DBA type, [this article](http://cc.davelozinski.com/sql/increase-sql-server-tempdb-performance) will give you some basic performance enhancing tips too.

Answer (score 0):

1. The temporary tables created in TempDB are dropped when the query is completed.
2. I'm not sure on this (I would have to try it), but I think theoretically ALL tables created in TempDB are visible, although only the user that created the table has permission to access it.

Comment: And is there any naming convention followed for the temp tables by the sql engine.

Comment: They are not dropped when the query is completed but when the connection is dropped or if the table itself is manually dropped.

Comment: I don't know, sorry. As far as I know, manually created temp tables (in the style #name) at least begin with this "#name" and then have an underscore and some numbers at the end. something like #name_0123456789. I don't know if this numbers have some special meaning though. AS for tables created for SORT, UNION etc., I have no idea.

Comment: @HLGEM: Manually created temp table, yes. But tables auto-generated for sorting, joining etc. are dropped when the query is completed.

Comment: Just to clarify, issuing DROP TABLE #foo (or dropping the connection, or exiting the scope) does not remove the table from tempdb right away.  Yes you can no longer access it since your connection is either gone or because your scope understands that you already issued a DROP, but the resources are still being used.  They are placed on a queue for destruction by a background process.

Comment: I actually uncovered a bug, inadvertently, in SQL Server 2005, which has since been fixed, where the destruction rate was not (tempdb resource usage was forcing us to reboot a particular production cluster as often as once a week until they issued us a private hotfix).