# Local vs Global temp tables - When to use what?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting, tempdb

I have a report which on execution connects to the database with `my_report_user` username. There can be many end-users of the report. And in each execution a new connection to the database will be made with `my_report_user` (there is no connection pooling)

I have a result set which I think can just be created once (may be on the first run of the report) and other report executions can just reuse that stuff. Basically each report execution should check whether this result set (stored as temp table) exists or not. If it does not exist then create that result set else just reuse whats available.

Should I use `local` temp tables (#) or `global` temp tables (##)?

Has anyone tried such stuff and if yes, please let me know what all things should I care about? (Almost simultaneous report runs, etc.)

EDIT: I am using Sql-Server 2005

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  If 2005+, CTEs (and possibly recursive CTEs) are another option.  Without knowing more about what you need to do with them, I recommend local over global temp tables...

Comment: Making a worst case assumption: that the global temp table doesn't get dropped because connections still exist to it, at what point does the data in that table become invalid? i.e., what defines when the data absolutely must be refreshed to avoid bad data in reports?

Comment: its sql-server 2005. Are you sure that local temp tables allows me the re-usability. I was thinking that local temp tables will not allow re-usability across multiple report executions. What do you say now knowing the version?

Comment: @Chris J, very nice question. The data is pretty much static and should be refreshed once in a month or so..But pls explain both the scenarios..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Neither**

If you want to cache result result sets under your own control, then you cannot use temp tables, of any kind. You should use ordinary user tables, stored either in tempdb or even have your own result set cache database.

Temp tables, bot #local and ##shared have a lifetime controlled by the connection(s). If your application disconnect, the temp table is deleted, and this does not work well with what you describe.

The real difficult prolem will be to populate these cached result sets under concurent runs without mixing things up (end up with result sets containing duplicate items from concurent report runs that both believed are the 'first' run).

As a side note SQL Server Reporting Services already does this out-of-the-box. You can cache and share datasets, you can cache and share reports, it already works and was tested for you.

Comment: "The real difficult prolem will be to populate these cached result sets under concurent runs without mixing things up" I am also worried about this thing. Thanks for the help, btw.

Comment: You can use app locks. Use a resource that identifies the report you're viewing, eg. "report sales north west fiscal october 2009", or "report id 42". 1. sp_getapplock 'shared', 'session'. 2. check the data set, if present, use it for report, then release app lock and exit. 3. if not present, release app loc, aquire it back X sp_getapplock 'exclusive', 'session'. 4. Check again if report exists, if not create it and use it, releae x lock and exit. 5. If report exists after X lock acquired, release x lock, go back to step 1.

Comment: I appreciate ur knowledge. But still there are chances that the result set is cleared off by the engine (when there are no active connections to that ## temp table). This defeats my caching-like purpose. What say? Though whatever locking mechanism you gave may hold good to solve the concurrency...

Comment: That's why I say don't use ##tables of any kind.

Answer (score 3):

I find #temp tables can be useful in certain scenarios, but not as a best practice.  I have yet to find a valid use for global ##temp tables, either in my own work, or in the work of anyone else who has written about them.  The only case I can think of is BCP or other external process which needs to build a temporary data store and then retrieve it in some subsequent step.  In that case I would prefer to use a permanent table with some kind of key and a background process to handle cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are getting into an OLTP mode now. Reading up on database warehousing will definitely help you.